# How to Control Multiple Wifi's, VPNs and App Access

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, internet-connection

#### What am I trying to do?

I think explaining this with some scenarios will make sense.

##### *Scenario 01*

Assume, I have two different WiFi Routers. Both of them have different Packages. On one it is just normal data and the other has a special package such as YouTube Unlimited. In that case I want to connect both WiFi Routers together and configure `WiFi Router A` to be able to work with any sites but not YouTube and  `WiFi Router B` to work only for YouTube.

##### *Scenario 02*

Assume, I am using two VPN's. One for my Company and the Other for my Personal. I want to connect both VPN`s but configure each VPN to route the traffic of the sites I specify. In this case company vpn should connect to my company sites and my personal vpn for sites other than company sites.

##### *Scenario 03*

Assume, I am using only one WiFi Router, It has both packages YouTube Unlimited and Normal Data Package. Now If I connect to a Personal VPN and go to YouTube it will be charged from my normal data package. In this case how to configure the VPN to route every traffic except YouTube.

##### *Scenario 04*

In case if I wan't particular Application don't have access to internet at all. How to block that app from using Internet at all.

---

**Scenarios can be endless, but I think these four scenarios will help you to understand what I am trying to do...**

**I am using a Windows PC, but I prefer a universal way of doing it on all platforms including Mobile phones**

---

#### Questions to Clarify?

1. Is it possible to have such a control over my network?
2. Is there any single software that can do all these together?
3. If not Is there a workaround to create this setup?

---

I think many people will want this kind of setup to have control on their network and internet...